# asp.net ScriptManager and UpdatePanel controls missing

Tags: asp.net

I have created a new ASP.NET Web Application, but the controls for ScriptManager and UpdatePanel are missing. After a fair bit of googling, and messing with the web.config, I am unable to get them installed properly.

I have another project in which they are installed and working, and I have copied all of the code from web.config across, but still no luck.

Maybe Visual Studio has a tool for installing it automatically?! Or is that wishful thinking?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the following to my web.config file ...

```
  <system.web>    
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of copying from another project, start it from scratch, it will probably save time :)

Here's an article to get you started : http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately the link didn't help. I have solved the issue now - see my answer